# Copy rows if value exists x amount of times

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables Board1 and Board2 with the identical structure. They both have a primary index column of `id`. I have a THIRD table called Table1, which has a non-indexed column `board_id`, where the same `board_id` occurs multiple times. `board_id` always corresponds to an `id` in Board1. Board2 is currently empty, and I want to add rows from Board1, but only where the same `board_id` occurs at least six times in Table1. Table1 will be changing periodically, so I'll be needing to do the query in the future, but without doubling `id` rows which are already in Board2.

So to recap:

There are three tables: Board1, Board2, and Table1. I want to copy rows from Board1 to Board2, but only where the `id` in the Board1 occurs (at least) six times in Table1 as `board_id'.

I'd appreciate any help!

EDIT: I'm dreadfully sorry, but I realized I made a huge mistake in my question. I've rewritten it to reflect what I actually needed. I'm truly sorry.

Comment: Please show your table structures.

Comment: @raheelshan I don't mind, but could you tell me how that would help? I want to copy all the columns to Table2, but all copying depends strictly on the 'id' and 'board_id' columns.

Comment: The exising answers still essentially answer your question, the group by sub query is the key.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
INSERT INTO Table2

SELECT
  id,
  board_id
FROM (SELECT
    b.id,
    b.board_id,
    bl.Count
      FROM board as b
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT
             board_id,
             COUNT(board_id) as `Count`
           FROM board
           GROUP BY board_id) as bl
      on bl.board_id = b.board_id
      group by b.id
      having bl.Count >= 6) as L
```

If you need more columns you can select them in inner and outer queries.

[Fiddle Demo for Select](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/833f2/3)

Comment: Why left join, absent `Board_Id`s will have a count less than six

Comment: you can use inner instead. Also counting and having i smanaging this thing (having bl.Count >= 6)

Comment: You don't do the existence check on `Table2.

Comment: OP said 'at least six times in the table'

Comment: Gentlemen, I truly apologize, I made a bad mistake in the question. I've edited it now...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the below:

- Add your column names where specified (excluding any ID columns), as I'm assuming each row will have a unique ID, so you won't be able to GROUP and COUNT by doing `SELECT * FROM Table1`

**You may need to test / validate this**

```
INSERT INTO Board2 (Your Column Names)
SELECT (Your Column Names)    
FROM Board1 
WHERE id (IN (SELECT board_id 
                    FROM  Table1 
                    GROUP BY (board_id) 
                    HAVING (COUNT(*) >= 6))    
AND board_id NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT board_id FROM Board2)
```

Comment: my answer should still be valid, I've just modified the table names slightly

Comment: Tanner, can I do INSERT INTO Board2 SELECT * FROM Board1 to grab all the columns/data?

Comment: Also, I should change the last line to AND id NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT id FROM Board2) , correct?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you asked for, with [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a49db/3)

```
INSERT Table2
SELECT
            *
    FROM
            Table1
        JOIN
            (
            SELECT
                    Board_Id,
                    count(*) cnt
                FROM
                    Table1
                GROUP BY
                    Board_Id
            ) BoardIds
                ON BoardIds.Board_Id = Table1.Board_Id
    WHERE
             BoardIds.cnt > 5
        AND
             NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.id = Table1.id)
```